# Problem between Matplotlib figure & the PyQt5/PySide2 QSplitter Widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, pyside2

I am trying to create 2 plot figures that can be auto-resized with the PyQt5/PySide2 QSplitter Widget. However, when I shrink the plots, their title and x-axis labels get overlapped, as shown below. It looks broken. Does anyone know better tricks to solve this problem?

Here is my sample code

```
import numpy as np
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')


class MyChart(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        canvas1 = FigureCanvasQTAgg(Figure(figsize=(20,12))) 
        ax1 = canvas1.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax1.plot(np.sin(np.linspace(0, 4, 1000)))
        ax1.set_title('Chart 1')

        canvas2 = FigureCanvasQTAgg(Figure(figsize=(20,12))) 
        ax2 = canvas2.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax2.plot(np.sin(5 * np.linspace(0, 4, 1000)))
        ax2.set_title('Chart 2')
        
        splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        splitter.addWidget(canvas1)
        splitter.addWidget(canvas2)
        self.setCentralWidget(splitter)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = MyChart()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jody from the [matplotlib forum](https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/problem-between-matplotlib-figure-pyqt5-pyside2-qsplitter-widget/21591/3), the solution was much simpler than I though. Just include `constrained_layout=True` in the figure constructor and that's it!! Here is the outcome.

```
...
canvas1 = FigureCanvasQTAgg(Figure(figsize=(20,12), constrained_layout=True)) 
...
canvas2 = FigureCanvasQTAgg(Figure(figsize=(20,12), constrained_layout=True)) 
...
```

[image]